# GNU Make: Building multiple source files without targets

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm using a makefile to check some configuration files before checking into version control. I am having difficulty with one of the rules, which needs to essentially just run

```
/usr/local/bin/check-program config/file1.conf
/usr/local/bin/check-program config/file2.conf
[...]
```

The *check-program* does not accept multiple arguments, so each config file needs to be checked individually. All the configuration files are in one subdirectory and all end in *.config*.

As there is no source/dependency relationship I haven't been able to find the correct makefile syntax to get this to run. As a work-around, a for-loop will do the check for me, but this will neither exit on failure nor skip a file that has already been checked.

Here is a cut-down version of what I have so far:

```
SHELL := /bin/sh
WD := $(shell pwd)
HOST := $(shell hostname -s)
BPCFG := $(wildcard config/*.conf)

all : check-bp

check-bp : $(BPCFG)
   for file in $(BPCFG); do \
       /usr/local/bin/check-program $$file; \
       echo ""; \
   done
```

Comment: "nor skip a file that has already been checked" - how would you know it was checked if you don't have resulting files? Maybe you should create empty marker files for each config, to use their modification date (and pattern rules too, as side effect)

Comment: Good point. I have implemented this per solution from @andrewdotn Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with sentinel files. For each `.conf` file, have the check step create a `.conf.checked` file if it succeeds.

```
SHELL := /bin/sh
WD := $(shell pwd)
HOST := $(shell hostname -s)
BPCFG := $(wildcard config/*.conf)

all : $(BCFG:%=%.checked)

%.conf.checked: %.conf
        /usr/local/bin/check-program $< && touch $@
```

As for the for loop not exiting on failure—that’s just the way shell works. Try

```
for ((i = 0; i < 10; i++)); do if (( $i < 9 )); then false; else true; fi; done
```

The command will fail 9 times out of ten, but all that counts is the the exit status of the last run through the loop.

To fix this, change the `SHELL` line to `SHELL = /bin/sh -e` to make the shell’s default behaviour be to abort scripts when a command fails. Since that will make shell commands abort even when you don’t mind that some things return non-zero exit statues, you may have to add `|| true` to the end of commands like `grep Warning error.log`.